# Trying to get pattern into specific shape - GIMP

Tags: gimp, mask

I am trying to get a specific pattern into a shape with GIMP using layer masks. But i cannot make it work, either the layer mask is grayscale for some reason or i cant get the pattern to show.

[image: This is the shape i want to use] 
This is the shape i am trying to fit the pattern into

[image: The texture i want to appear only in the shape]
And this is the texture i want, but only in the shape above

I assume it has something to do with getting a transparent layer made and then making adding the texture as a layer mask or something. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On the green layer: *Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection*
- Hide the green layer
- On the other layer: *Layer>Mask>Add layer mask* and initialize to selection.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize to selection" ?

Comment: *Layer>Mask>Add layer mask* leads to a dialog where the top line says: *Initialize layer mask to:* and one of the choices is *Selection*